# Can't connect to any wifi ap using external wifi adapter Virtualbox

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, virtualbox

- Host OS: Ubuntu 19.xx (also tried Parrot OS home 4.9)
- Guest OS:Kali linux 2020.1b ; Kali linux 2019.3; Parrot OS security 4.9
- VirtualBox v=6.1.6
- Wireless adapter : alfa 036nh
- firmware-ralink package is installed

  My problem: I insert my wireless adapter to the guest os (devices->usb->ralink802.11n) but i'm not able to connect to any wifi ap. In Kali linux  Network manager notifies:"activation of network connection failed".Parrot  OS 's network manager just stops showing other wireless networks and behaves in similar way.

Before you ask... The following solutions don't help:
sudo service network-restart;
sudo nmcli networking on;
ifconfig ...down/up;
reconnecting my alfa to the guest os.

I'm new to linux so i don't know what can i do else. And something else... In Host Parrot OS home edition everything's fine

Answer (score 0):

First of all check the logs, this is your starting point in any debug process.

- `journalctl -u NetworkManager`
- `journalctl -u wpa_supplicant`
- `/var/log/syslog`(or `/var/log/mesages` I am not sure which does Kali has.)

`wpa_supplicant.service` is the client that is taking care of the authentication for the wireless.

I would suggest that the connection is not bridged between the host and the VM. You can do that in the VMWare player settings. If it is bridged then try with manual setting ip, gateway etc. and if it works debug why the DHCP is not working.